# Using tel: tag in windows phone 8 to initiate a call with a phone extension

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, tel

I have a very simple page which has a phone number link that can be click to make a call.

```
<a href="tel:5555555,555">555-5555 ext. 555</a>
```

this is currently working fine with the IOS devices i tried and some later models of android phones. However Windows phone 8 with IE10 doesnt seem like it. Has anyone encountered this problem before? What will be the best way to do this in WP8? 
Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

I tried on this website : http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-telephone-number-links-with-html5 on my Lumia 920 and it works.

Comment: it works when you don't need to call the extension. In my case, after you click on the number, it dials the first part which is the 5555555. On IOS, it will have an other option "dial" on the bottom of the calling page, then you can click to make the extension call. However it is not happening on the WP8.

Comment: @StvS for googler's mobiles are not often behind extensions so for the most part this is correct but i think there is an option in WP7 to auto dial before dialing the number so you set that to go though your extension.